# When the ".php" at the end of PHP Files is removed, it becomes 302 redirect

Tags: nginx, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

I remove the `.php` file attachment in the application, but this time the application's action pages do not work. Because I removed the `.php` suffix at the end of the files.

For example, I want to send data to a `collect` file with AJAX but I get 302 returns.

https://panel.example.com/application/collect

There is no problem with other files of the application.

```
https://panel.example.com/login
*Version without rewrite:*
https://panel.example.com/index.php?cmd=login
```

How can I fix the 302 redirect issue in the app's working files? Where am I doing wrong?

```
location / {
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
} 

rewrite ^/([^/]+)/([^/]+)?$ /index.php?cmd=$1&scd=$2 break;
rewrite ^/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?cmd=$1 break;
```

The above code is not included in the [full configuration file](https://pastebin.com/03s90FQu). I have uploaded the clean file.

---

CURL by CMD;

```
C:\Users\emres>curl -I https://panel.example.com/application/collect
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Server: nginx/1.18.0
Date: Sun, 02 Jan 2022 12:32:57 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Connection: keep-alive
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=pvn7l2g8babucp9a9mkuo5ll0v; path=/; domain=.example.com
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Location: https://panel.example.com/login?returnBack=http://panel.example.com/application/collect
```

error.log:

*clean*.

access.log:

```
192.168.1.145 - - [02/Jan/2022:15:36:22 +0300] "GET /application/collect HTTP/1.1" 302 5 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.93 Safari/537.36 OPR/82.0.4227.33"
192.168.1.145 - - [02/Jan/2022:15:36:22 +0300] "GET /login?returnBack=https://panel.example.com/application/collect HTTP/1.1" 200 3977 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.93 Safari/537.36 OPR/82.0.4227.33"
192.168.1.145 - - [02/Jan/2022:15:36:22 +0300] "GET /libs/out/general-js.php?v=61d19c464ab3b HTTP/1.1" 200 390 "https://panel.example.com/login?returnBack=https://panel.example.com/application/collect" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.93 Safari/537.36 OPR/82.0.4227.33"
192.168.1.145 - - [02/Jan/2022:15:36:22 +0300] "POST /application/collect HTTP/1.1" 302 5 "https://panel.example.com/login?returnBack=https://panel.example.com/application/collect" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.93 Safari/537.36 OPR/82.0.4227.33"
192.168.1.145 - - [02/Jan/2022:15:36:22 +0300] "GET /login?returnBack=https://panel.example.com/application/collect HTTP/1.1" 200 3981 "https://panel.example.com/login?returnBack=https://panel.example.com/application/collect" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.93 Safari/537.36 OPR/82.0.4227.33"
```

---

Nginx: 1.18

Comment: It's not clear where the 302 is originating. Can you show the full output from `curl -I https://panel.example.com/application/collect` together with the access and error log entries.

Comment: Hi  @RichardSmith , I updated my question according to your request.

Comment: I think it detects "application/collect" path differently. It detects it as `application` for `cmd` and `collect` for `scd` for index.php

Comment: That's exactly what's happening. Have you just renamed `collect.php` to `collect`, because that will break everything. Your configuration requires that PHP files end with `.php`. If you want to implement extension-less PHP there are better ways to do it.

Comment: The server I am currently using is Apache and I am using it with Nginx. I want to deprecate Apache now. Altogether Nginx would be the best but I ran into this issue. It would be very difficult for me to make one more subfolder to the "application" folder. Because it will require major changes in the whole structure. What is your suggestion? cc @RichardSmith